# Prevent objects deletion from Google Storage

Tags: windows, backup, storage, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I bought CloudBerry Ultimate software ([Link for more information](https://secure.shareit.com:443/shareit/product.html?cart=1&productid=300505564&languageid=1&affiliateid=200254654)) to make backups. On that software I can control when the software deletes the objects I backed up, but I want to be sure that will be impossible to delete files from my Google Storage Nearline, I know that Amazon Web Services have the Amazon Glacier with VaultLock that prevents to delete objects for a period of time and is impossible to delete (even if you have all administrative privileges) any object or modify the parameters.

Does any one know how can I prevent to delete any object from my Google Nearline account?

Comment: I'm looking for something like this: [Create Write-Once-Read-Many Archive Storage with Amazon Glacier](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/glacier-vault-lock/) but the equivalent for Google Storage Nearline.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. There's no such thing similar to Glacier Vault Lock.
 You can temporary suspend a user though.

> You can temporarily block a user's access to your organization's
>   Google services by suspending their account. This doesn't delete their
>   email, documents, calendars, or other data. And their shared documents
>   remain accessible to collaborators. But the user can no longer sign in
>   to their account. Also, new email and calendar invitations are
>   blocked. After suspending a user, you can restore the account at any
>   time.

https://support.google.com/a/answer/33312

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking for DELETE permissions, I need that no one can delete objects (even the administrator or someone with admin permissions).

Comment: @HelloWorld, My bad, will update the question. it's not possible since there's no such a thing in Google similar to Glacier Vault lock.

Answer (score -1):

You can use bucket Lock feature, which allows you to configure a data retention policy for a Cloud Storage bucket that governs how long objects in the bucket must be retained. The feature also allows you to lock the data retention policy, permanently preventing the policy from being reduced or removed.
reference: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/bucket-lock

or

you can give only permission to create, view, list objects to the service account used by the software.
ref: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles